# R "read.table" function gives only odd numbered columns while merging the even numbered columns

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to read a TSV file in R using the read.table function.

```
myTable <- read.table("file_path", sep='\t', header=T)
```

But when I try the command

```
names(myTable)
```

It gives me column names which are odd numbered, while merging the even numbered columns with those.

```
[1] "GeneSymbol"    "GSM480304_JK_C_05.07.mas5.chp"
[3] "GSM480355_JK_C_05.07.mas5.chp"    "GSM480480_JK_C_05.07.mas5.chp"
[5] "GSM480555_JK_C_05.07.mas5.chp"    "GSM480634_JK_C_05.07.mas5.chp"
```

These are exact column names and you can see that two column names are separated by space while only ODD numbered column names are listed.

The output should be like this:

```
[1] "GeneSymbol"
[2] "GSM480304_JK_C_05.07.mas5.chp"
[3] "GSM480355_JK_C_05.07.mas5.chp"
[4] "GSM480480_JK_C_05.07.mas5.chp"
[5] "GSM480555_JK_C_05.07.mas5.chp"
[6] "GSM480634_JK_C_05.07.mas5.chp"
```

This is creating problem in assigning names to another table where I want to use these column names. Any suggestions ?

Comment: That's just how R prints the vector.. when there is no space for the next element it skips to the next line, in your case it happens to be two elements per row. Try `dput(names(myTable))` or `str(names(myTable))` to see what they actually look like.

Comment: try `utils::View(myTable)` and see what it looks like (assuming you use Rstudio)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in the comments, R is displaying all the columns, but not in the format you expect. This can be forced by casting the result of `names()` with `as.data.frame()` as follows:

```
rawData <- "
Number,Name,Type1,Type2,Total,HP,Attack,Defense,SpecialAtk,SpecialDef,Speed,Generation,Legendary
1,Bulbasaur,Grass,Poison,318,45,49,49,65,65,45,1,False
2,Ivysaur,Grass,Poison,405,60,62,63,80,80,60,1,False
3,Venusaur,Grass,Poison,525,80,82,83,100,100,80,1,False
3,VenusaurMega Venusaur,Grass,Poison,625,80,100,123,122,120,80,1,False
4,Charmander,Fire,,309,39,52,43,60,50,65,1,False
5,Charmeleon,Fire,,405,58,64,58,80,65,80,1,False
6,Charizard,Fire,Flying,534,78,84,78,109,85,100,1,False
6,CharizardMega Charizard X,Fire,Dragon,634,78,130,111,130,85,100,1,False
6,CharizardMega Charizard Y,Fire,Flying,634,78,104,78,159,115,100,1,False
7,Squirtle,Water,,314,44,48,65,50,64,43,1,False
8,Wartortle,Water,,405,59,63,80,65,80,58,1,False
9,Blastoise,Water,,530,79,83,100,85,105,78,1,False"

gen01 <- read.csv(textConnection=rawData,header=TRUE)

as.data.frame(names(gen01))
```

...and the output:

```
> as.data.frame(names(gen01))
   names(gen01)
1        Number
2          Name
3         Type1
4         Type2
5         Total
6            HP
7        Attack
8       Defense
9    SpecialAtk
10   SpecialDef
11        Speed
12   Generation
13    Legendary
```